Sieve filter does not trigger even the "To" field contains the search string
I have this sieve filter in my Proton Mail account:
require ["include", "environment", "variables", "relational", "comparator-i;ascii-numeric", "spamtest"];
require ["fileinto", "imap4flags"];

# Generated: Do not run this script on spam messages
if allof (environment :matches "vnd.proton.spam-threshold" "*", spamtest :value "ge" :comparator "i;ascii-numeric" "${1}") {
    return;
}

/**
 * @type or
 * @comparator contains
 * @comparator contains
 */
if anyof (address :all :comparator "i;unicode-casemap" :contains "From" "@example.org", address :all :comparator "i;unicode-casemap" :contains ["To", "Cc", "Bcc"] "@example.org") {
    fileinto "My filter";
}

The expected behavior is it should move an email to "My filter" folder if either the "From" or "To" field contains the "@example.org" text.
It works for most emails, but some are not moved.
Real example (just changed the domain to "@example.org", removed unrelated headers and obfuscated real names):
Return-Path: <info-return-490-myaddress=protonmail.com@example.org>
X-Original-To: myaddress@protonmail.com
Delivered-To: myaddress@protonmail.com
Authentication-Results: mail.protonmail.ch; spf=pass smtp.mailfrom=example.org
Mailing-List: contact info-help@example.org; run by ezmlm
Precedence: bulk
X-No-Archive: yes
List-Post: <mailto:info@example.org>
List-Help: <mailto:info-help@example.org>
List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:info-unsubscribe@example.org>
List-Subscribe: <mailto:info-subscribe@example.org>
Reply-To: info@example.org
From: John Doe <johndoe@foo.com>
Date: Mon, 27 May 2024 21:35:04 +0200
To: info@example.org
Content-Type: text/html
X-Spam-Rating: mxdhbe07.ad.aruba.it 1.6.2 0/1000/N
Subject: Re: [Gruppo info] Re: gruppo info

The "To" field clearly contains the "@example.org" text.
So, why the code above does not trigger?
Here another example of an email I sent to the "@example.org" domain that was not moved:
From: John Doe <myaddress@protonmail.com>
Date: Thu, 30 May 2024 06:07:31 +0000
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html
To: info@example.org <info@example.org>


About the closing vote: I've asked on meta [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/430434/is-proton-sieve-filter-a-programming-language] if sieve is a programming language.

I don't believe anyone can directly answer "why the code above does not trigger?" without access to logs showing how the filter was (or in your case wasn't) applied to any given message.
However, in situations where the address command doesn't match as expected in Proton Mail, I've had success with the envelope command (see "Advanced" section further down from the "Performing tests on headers" section).
require ["include", "environment", "variables", "relational", "comparator-i;ascii-numeric", "spamtest"];
require ["fileinto", "imap4flags", "envelope"];

# Generated: Do not run this script on spam messages
if allof (environment :matches "vnd.proton.spam-threshold" "*", spamtest :value "ge" :comparator "i;ascii-numeric" "${1}") {
    return;
}

/**
 * @type or
 * @comparator contains
 * @comparator contains
 */
if anyof (envelope :all :comparator "i;unicode-casemap" :contains "From" "@example.org", envelope :all :comparator "i;unicode-casemap" :contains "To" "@example.org") {
    fileinto "My filter";
}

You could further clarify this by using :domain instead of :all (see previous link):
require ["include", "environment", "variables", "relational", "comparator-i;ascii-numeric", "spamtest"];
require ["fileinto", "imap4flags", "envelope"];

# Generated: Do not run this script on spam messages
if allof (environment :matches "vnd.proton.spam-threshold" "*", spamtest :value "ge" :comparator "i;ascii-numeric" "${1}") {
    return;
}

/**
 * 
 */
if anyof (envelope :domain :comparator "i;unicode-casemap" "From" "example.org", envelope :domain :comparator "i;unicode-casemap" "To" "example.org") {
    fileinto "My filter";
}

Note that editing the filter directly will remove the ability to edit it in Proton Mail's step-by-step editor.
